# Is there an alternative to multiple left joins on subselect?

Tags: sql

I have a history table that is tracking every time a group member acknowledges an item, recording the group ID, item ID, history ID, and history_time. A view my predecessor created partially pulls from this to return the MAX(history_time) for each group ID for a given item ID in an effort to return only the most recent date a group acknowledged an item, returning null if a group hasn't acknowledged it. This has resulted in this portion of the view relying on 24 LEFT JOINS.

A simplified example of this is below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 

ITEM_TABLE item LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT ITEM_ID, MAX(HISTORY_TIME) AS [202_TIME]
    FROM dbo.HISTORY AS HISTORY_1
    WHERE (GROUP_ID = 202)
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID) AS h1 ON h1.ITEM_ID = item.ITEM_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT ITEM_ID, MAX(HISTORY_TIME) AS [145_TIME]
    FROM dbo.HISTORY AS HISTORY_2
    WHERE (GROUP_ID = 145)
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID) AS h2 ON h2.ITEM_ID = item.ITEM_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN

....
```

The sub-selects in the FROM clause are repeated for every group (20+). It just seems messy, in my opinion. I tried replacing all of these extra joins with one large select that utilizes ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION to aggregate the data and push it into a PIVOT table. While I feel like this looks much nicer, it is obviously slower than I would like.

Are there any alternatives that are cleaner, easier to read, or more efficient than SELECTing from multiple joins on subselects?

Comment: Does your item_table have a group_id column?

Comment: @Meckel'sDiverticulum Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

You can try the max(case expression) to find out the max_timings for each of the group ids using a single select as follows

```
   SELECT *
     FROM ITEM_TABLE item
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ITEM_ID
                 , MAX(CASE WHEN GROUP_ID=202 THEN HISTORY_TIME END) AS [202_TIME]
                 , MAX(CASE WHEN GROUP_ID=145 THEN HISTORY_TIME END) AS [145_TIME]
            FROM dbo.HISTORY 
            WHERE (GROUP_ID in (202,145,...)
            GROUP BY ITEM_ID)h1 
       ON h1.ITEM_ID = item.ITEM_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care for the pivoted format, you could use a `correlated subquery` after pulling in the respective group_ids to the item_table using a `left-join`.

```
select 
a.group_id as group_id,
a.item_id as item_id, 
(select max(history_time) from history_table b WHERE b.group_id=a.group_id) as max_history
from 
(select i.*, h.group_id from item_table i left join history_table h on i.item_id=h.item_id) a
group by a.group_id, a.item_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Correlated subqueries are likely to have better performance:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELECT MAX(HISTORY_TIME)
        FROM dbo.HISTORY AS HISTORY_1
        WHERE h.GROUP_ID = 202 AND
              h.ITEM_ID = item.ITEM_ID
       ) as [202_TIME],
       (SELECT MAX(HISTORY_TIME)
        FROM dbo.HISTORY AS HISTORY_1
        WHERE h.GROUP_ID = 405 AND
              h.ITEM_ID = item.ITEM_ID
       ) as [405_TIME]
FROM ITEM_TABLE item i;
```

For performance, you want an index on `HISTORY(ITEM_ID, GROUP_ID, HISTORY_TIME)`.

You might get somewhat better performance using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT i.*, h.[202_TIME], h.[405_TIME]
FROM ITEM_TABLE item i OUTER APPLY
       (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN h.GROUP_ID = 202 THEN HISTORY_TIME END) as [202_TIME],
               MAX(CASE WHEN h.GROUP_ID = 405 THEN HISTORY_TIME END) as [405_TIME]
        FROM dbo.HISTORY AS HISTORY_1
        WHERE h.GROUP_ID IN (202, 405) AND
              h.ITEM_ID = item.ITEM_ID
       ) h;
```

The same index is recommended.  If you add more groups, then the performance advantage of this approach should increase.